# Electrified Fences

Tags: electricity

On a chilling visit to Auchwitz-Birkenau saw the electrified fences, still intact; though, no longer live. The white insulators prevented the current running to earth, down the posts, but what happened to the current-flow when it rained?

Comment: Perhaps they switched off the current?

Answer (score 1):

In order for it to be a current flow, there must be a continuous conductive path between two materials of different potential.

The water streaming over an insulator is unlikely to provide such a continuous path to ground. The insulator will therefore still work as intended. Note that this happens every day all over the world on all overhead power lines, transformer stations, and most other outdoor electrical equipment.

If however, there was a continuous path to ground at some point, then there would be a flow of current to ground, but this would stop once the path was broken. For some systems, this would cause relays to trip in order to break this potentially dangerous current. I suspect that in Auchwitz-Birkenau, the relays had the exact opposite functionality.

<sub>I'm assuming for simplicity that there won't be standing arcs after the path is broken, which should be a safe assumption.</sub>